# Is there a way to specify that all letters in a document are capitalized in Google Cloud Vision API document text detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I have several handwritten documents that were written in all caps. When comparing results of OCR with the original documents, almost all errors come from reading it in lowercase.
BUILDINGS is read as Buchonas, RED is reco, OCCASIONAL is deCAS AL.

Is there a way to specify to Vision API, in Python, that a document contains only numbers and capital letters? To add some sort of image context like "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890,.-!?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.